# How can I find the intended render width of an element using jQuery before it is rendered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an element, e.g. below, that is not yet appended to the `body`. I can work with it fine, it has all the classes that *will* cause it to render with a particular box model.

But I need to know its width *before* it is actually appended.

If I use Firebug to inspect the element, it correctly calculates the box model and layout using the element itself and CSS. But how can I do so from within jQuery?

```
<li>
  <i class="icon"></i>
  <a>/a>
</li>
```

The css, e.g. for `i.icon` sets `width: 40;`, but how do I get that?

All of the variants on `elm.width()` give 0, including `elm.css('width')`

Comment: You can't, you have to append it, but you can hide it...

Comment: If you mean before adding it to the dom then I don't think it is possible because the styles associated with the element will be applied only after the element is added to the dom....

Comment: Append it to the DOM but set `display:none` (or use `.hide()`) then you can get any style attributes you need and then remove it.

Comment: *"The css, e.g. for `i.icon` sets `width: 40;`"* That's invalid CSS. 40 what? `px`? `em`? `%`?

Comment: @Archer: `display:none` will give the element size of 0. One can use `visibility="hidden"` – though that will cause *"empty space"*.

Comment: @user13500 Normally, I'd agree with you, but I tried it on this page before posting.

Comment: @Archer: Indeed. Using jQuery `.width()` is OK. If I read the jQuery source correct the element is extended with the a bit odd named `cssShow` style before measuring: `position: "absolute", visibility: "hidden", display: "block"`. So to summarize. If using `width()` then OK. If reading width/height directly, not OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get its computed properties without adding it to the document. However, you can add it, get the computed properties, and then remove it, almost certainly without the user noticing. E.g.:

```
var $elm = /*...the jQuery wrapper around your element...*/;

// Append it
$elm.appendTo(document.body); // Put it where it should go, not usually `document.body` literally

// Get the properties here, e.g.:
var width = $elm.width();

// Remove it again
$elm.remove();
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/jufak/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/jufak/1/edit)

Comment: I wish. It doesn't seem to work. Even putting the entire `li` in the DOM by appending to `body` gives width for the `li`, but not for the child elements.

Comment: @deitch: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/jufak/2 (source: http://jsbin.com/jufak/2/edit). Note that to give an `i` element width, you have to set its `display` property, because its default `display` property is `inline` and you can't give inline elements widths. (You also need units on the width.)

Comment: @deitch: And using `40%` instead (rather than `40px` in the above), just so the number varies: http://jsbin.com/jufak/5 (source: http://jsbin.com/jufak/5/edit)

Comment: thanks I will see if I can simplify it down to reproducible on a jsbin. Of course, once I do, I will probably solve it.. :-)

Comment: Of course, it would really be nice if there were a "give me what this element would look like if it were rendered right now". After all, Firebug successfully does it.

Comment: @deitch: Well, effectively, there is; the above. :-) Because the browser can't be *sure* what the element will look like without knowing where you're putting it. So putting it there is a fairly direct way to find out what it would be. I *think* there are some edge cases, though, where you have to use `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 0)` after appending, before measuring/removing (which the user ***might*** notice, maybe), to wait for reflow to happen, though I'm not sure that's really true anymore (if it ever was). So yeah, a "if I were to put this here, what would it look like?" would be nice.

Comment: @TJ I think you were right. It actually does work, but the CSS used to style it depends on its location. In this case, the `i` inside the `li` inside a particular class of `div`. Would be really nice if I could just sort of do a "CSS query". I will work around it, and when I get it to work according to your solution, will flag it as correct. Thanks for posting it.

Comment: So it turns out I didn't even need to append it to the body. As long as it is in the DOM, it works. Not sure about every browser, but certainly in FF.

Comment: @deitch: Right. You append it where you want it (you *have* to, it affects the layout of the element otherwise). Sorry if I gave you the impression it had to be `document.body`; the "works for me" above uses a `ul` (because we're appending an `li`).

Comment: @TJ, it got doubly more complicated. First, depends on the browser. FF was OK with just having it on the DOM, but Chrome and Safari insisted it be in the body. Second, if your framework adds a CSS `link` tag, then the width can be 0 or real, depending on if you take `.width()` before or after the browser finishes loading the URL in the `link` tag!